# How to find this directional derivative (Schaum’s Outline: Differential Geometry 7.49, pg.149)

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative

> Let
> $$
> \mathbf{f}(\mathbf{x}) = (x_1 + x_2)^2\mathbf{e}_1 + x_1\sin x_2\mathbf{e}_2,\quad \mathbf{x}_0 = \mathbf{e}_1 + \pi\mathbf{e}_2:
> $$
> Find
> $D_{\mathbf{v}_0 \mathbf{u}_0}\mathbf{f}$
> where $\mathbf{u}_0 = (\mathbf{e}_1 + 2\mathbf{e}_2)$ and $\mathbf{v}_0 = (\mathbf{e}_1 - \mathbf{e}_2)$.

How would I approach this problem? Apologies for the poor formatting, this is my first time on the website. I put a better image here. See part (c).
[image: I put a better image here. Part (c).]

Comment: This is certainly not differential geometry. It's plain old multivariable calculus, so I will alter the tags. Where are you getting stuck? Please edit your post to include a specific question. Where are having difficulties? (By the way, such a question would essentially never show up in a differential geometry course.)

Comment: I assume that notation is asking for $D_{u_0}(D_{v_0} f)(x_0)$.

Comment: Hint: the directional derivative can be expressed as a dot product (see, for example, Stewart or Thomas).

Answer (score 1):

There is a little typo in (c), it should be $D^2_{\mathbf{v}_0 \mathbf{u}_0}\mathbf{f}(\mathbf{x}_0)$. We have that
$$D^2\mathbf{f}(\mathbf{x})=\begin{bmatrix}
        2\mathbf{e}_1 & 2\mathbf{e}_1+\cos(x_2)\mathbf{e}_2  \\
2\mathbf{e}_1+\cos(x_2)\mathbf{e}_2 & 2\mathbf{e}_1-x_1\sin(x_2)\mathbf{e}_2 
        \end{bmatrix},$$
and at the given point $\mathbf{x}_0=\mathbf{e}_1+\pi\mathbf{e}_2$, we find
$$D^2\mathbf{f}(\mathbf{x}_0)=\begin{bmatrix}
        2\mathbf{e}_1 & 2\mathbf{e}_1-\mathbf{e}_2  \\
2\mathbf{e}_1-\mathbf{e}_2 & 2\mathbf{e}_1 
        \end{bmatrix}.$$
It remains to evaluate (see Theorem 7.11, a few pages before, in same the book),
$$
\begin{align}
D^2_{\mathbf{v}_0 \mathbf{u}_0}\mathbf{f}(\mathbf{x}_0)&=2\mathbf{e}_1 u_1v_1+(2\mathbf{e}_1-\mathbf{e}_2)(u_1v_2+u_2v_1)+2\mathbf{e}_1 u_2v_2\\
&=2\mathbf{e}_1(1\cdot 1)+(2\mathbf{e}_1-\mathbf{e}_2)(1\cdot -1+2\cdot 1)+2\mathbf{e}_1 (2\cdot-1)\\
&=2\mathbf{e}_1+2\mathbf{e}_1-\mathbf{e}_2-4\mathbf{e}_1=-\mathbf{e}_2.\end{align}$$